# Python: "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous"

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a new table for MySQL server and the data drawn will come from a excel file that I have downloaded. However, I was unable to execute my query as I am faced with the error "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Sample of Data:
[image]

Here are my codes

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

survey = pd.read_excel("surveyraw.xlsx")
pd.DataFrame(survey)

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
password="***",
database="***"
)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute
(
"CREATE TABLE survey (resp_id VARCHAR(64), var VARCHAR(128), val VARCHAR(64))"
)

insert_query = "INSERT INTO survey (resp_id, var, val) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

cursor.executemany(insert_query, survey.to_records(index=False))
connection.commit()
```

Error Code:

```
ValueError: ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ab80c19b7fda> in <module>
----> 1 cursor.executemany(insert_query, 
survey.to_records(index=False))
  2 connection.commit()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py in executemany(self, operation, seq_params)
373         data using the execute() method.
374         """
375         if not operation or not seq_params:
376             return None
377 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the full error code and a sample of your data. I assume that the error happen at `cursor.executemany(insert_query, survey)`. This is because the function expects a list of records instead of a DataFrame. You could try:

```
cursor.executemany(insert_query, survey.to_records(index=False))
```

Comment: @Z Li Hi, I have edited my question with a sample of data as well as adding the full error code